# Getting a list of strings from a column and sorting them alphabetically

Tags: sql

Say I have a column of strings and I want to grab this list and send it as a list to someone to look through, however the strings are not sorted alphabetically.. Is there anyway to sort these results alphabetically without actually rearranging the data in the column?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the `ORDER BY` clause?

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY yourcolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to sort these results alphabetically without actually
>   rearranging the data in the column?

Do you mean

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
ORDER BY somefield;
```

This will sort the table alphapitacally, assuming that the `ORDER BY` field is a string. But this won't rearrange the data in that column.